# Why can't I remove these divs with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have dynamically created elements within a parent element of `.output` which are created within my `on('click')` function.

```
$(document).on("click", '#search', function() {   
//Loop crime data array from api request above...
for(var i = 0; i < mapData.length; i++) {

  //Fill in crime data
  var fill = '<div class="row resu"><div class="col-xs-2 number"><h5>'+[i+1]+'</h5></div><div class="col-xs-10"><p class="text-primary">Type of crime: <span class="text-strong">'+mapData[i][0]+'</span></p><p class="text-primary">Location specifics: <span class="text-strong">'+mapData[i][1]+'</span></p></div></div>';

  //add to div
  $('.output').append(fill);  
}
...
.......
```

But nowhere outside the function am I able to target the new `.resu` rows for which I can apply `.empty()` or `.remove()`. Every time I hit the search button I wish to empty the output container div first.

If you go to my pen and hit the button, you will see some information regarding crime in that postcode's area. If you keep pressing it then multiple duplications of the same information will fill it up. How can I get rid of those with jquery?

My pen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xrwXYy

Comment: you can add a demo using `<>` not all SO people will go to an external link just to check the demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the update DEMO: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PjPJaZ

The isuue is, You are adding data to `mapData` array after each request. You need to reset the `mapData` array after each request as well.

```
function getPolApi(year,month,lat,lng,mapData) {
    $.ajax({
    url : "https://data.police.uk/api/crimes-at-location?date="+year+"-"+month+"&lat="+lat+"&lng="+lng,
    type : "get",
    async: false,
    success : function(data) {
     mapData = [];// Empty the array
      for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {      
            mapData.push([
              data[i]['category'],
              data[i]['location']['street']['name'],
            ]);

           heatmapData.push(new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].location.latitude,data[i].location.longitude));
      }
       //Add results into view

          for(var i = 0; i < mapData.length; i++) {
             var fill = '<div class="row resu"><div class="col-xs-2 number"><h5>'+[i+1]+'</h5></div><div class="col-xs-10"><p class="text-primary">Type of crime: <span class="text-strong">'+mapData[i][0]+'</span></p><p class="text-primary">Location specifics: <span class="text-strong">'+mapData[i][1]+'</span></p></div></div>';
            $('.output').append(fill);

          }//endforloop

          //Move the map into view of the heatmaps
          moveMap(lat,lng);
          //Add the heatmaps
          addHeatMap();
      mapData = [];
      // console.log(mapData);
    },
    error: function(dat) {
       console.log('error');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to invoke 'getCords' asynchronously, you will find that the `#output` is actually be cleared before being replenished. So there must be something wrong with your `getCords` or `getPolApi`.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    getCords(postcode);
    getPolApi(year,month,lat,lng,mapData);
},3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
 $('.output').html(fill);
```

instead of

```
 $('.output').append(fill);
```

In that case there is no need to remove `resu`

Answer (score 0):

You are doing right with `output` div.

But you missed out the `mapData` variable to be empty.

Each time its getting push in your ajax success response for loop.

So you need to clear `mapData` veriable.